# Read data from a network address in C#

Tags: c#, string, networking, port, using

How can I read information about a network address using C# code in Visual Studio?
(Copy to a string variable is enough for me)

The address of this form

10.15.33.10:8080/clarity/fsm.jsp

Comment: What kind of information are you trying to read? JSP suggests that this is a web page, not an API or something you can "read" data from. Can you explain more about what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to read the source of the web page, then this code could help you:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()){
   string content = await client.GetStringAsync("http://google.com");
   Console.WriteLine(content);
}
```

Replace http://google.com with your website-url.

Comment: Thanks for answering,The address in question is not a web address but an address on an internal network

Comment: I want a method like this, but for an address on the internal network and not in the web server (I think it should be based on socket programming in C#), can you tell what the last part of the address that separated by slash? (MY NETWORK ADRRESS=ip:port/  "What is the name of this part of the address?" )